# select * from here where THIS IS CHECKED

Tags: database, datagrid, checkbox, vb6

i am looking for a way to show data that are Checked(1) in my Database to a DataGrid, excluding those UnChecked(0)..

**Sample Database:**

**Fruits?**
Apple - 1
Mouse - 0
Grapes - 1
Pencil - 0
Orange - 1

**Button_Click**

... on DataGrid display only checked Data / Rows

Comment: Why dont have data saved as 0 & 1 instead of checked and unchecked? Do you need sql query?

Comment: @AshReva no not sql.. i am not yet familiar with that.. :D yes that's it.. sorry about that, just thought it is much understandable.. thanks i'll edit it now.

Comment: Set myRecordSet = myConnection.Execute("select * from myTable where is_it_fruit = 1") ....  and then ....... 
Set DataGrid.DataSource = myRecordSet

Comment: got it working.. "select * from here where THIS like 'true'"

Answer (score 0):

this will help you to add checkbox column in grid then make code for checked & unchecked as per your database. same way you can fetch the data on the WHERE condition of the checked row cell value...

```
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
    checkColumn.Name = "X";
    checkColumn.HeaderText = "X";
    checkColumn.Width = 50;
    checkColumn.ReadOnly = false;
    checkColumn.FillWeight = 10; 
    //if the datagridview is resized (on form resize) the checkbox won't take up too much; value is relative to the other columns' fill values
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(checkColumn);
```